# Python - Issue SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED

Tags: python, ssl

I'm trying to solve the problem

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:579)
```

when I connect to a handle server.

I also used

```
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
```

as some user suggested, but I'm not able to fix the issue.

Any other solution?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide python version and your OS

Comment: @Antwane Centos 7 and Python 2.7.5

Comment: were you able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Does your server have a valid certificate, signed by a Certification Authority?

If it uses a self-signed certificate I would suggest that you save a copy of the public certificate in your Python project and pass the certificate name in the verify parameter on requests.

You can save the certificate by accessing the server on Firefox, clicking on the Lock icon near to the address bar, selecting the Certificate, then More details, then View Certificate, then export.

You will get a .pem file, let's say: "my_server_certificate.pem".

Then when you create your Session object on requests you can pass the parameter:

```
session = requests.Session()
session.verify = "my_server_certificate.pem"
```

I had similar problems when using charles proxy with my Python scripts. I hope this helps you solve your problem as well.

Comment: I get `__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'verify'`. I read that Session no longer takes arguments in its constructor. Currently the documentation is out of date on this. I tried `session = requests.Session()` and 
`session.verify = False` but the issue still occurs.

Comment: My bad. Yeah, you have to create the session then set session.verify = "my_server_certificate.pem"

Comment: Edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: I also tried your solution but it doesn't work. To answer to your first question.... yes, the server uses a self-signed certificate. I have no idea how to solve the issue...

Comment: Did you copy the server's certificate to your Python script folder?

Comment: The exported certificate has .crt extension. I put it on Desktop and I provided tha absolute path to session.verify call.